# Is there a method in jdbc driver that convert from java.sql types to correct sql string?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle, jdbc

I'm maintaining an old project that runs on mysql db. I have to migrate this project from mysql to oracle db maintaining the compatibility with old db (mysql). In that project there are a lot of query build manually, then i cannot use the PreparedStatement interface and set parameters to execute querys, but i build manually the query string and use simply Statement. So I would know if is there a method in jdbc driver that convert from java.sql types to the correct sql string (quoted or not), in particular for date format.

For code:

```
Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
try {
  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
System.out.println(date.toString());
```

The output is:

> 2015-10-23

both if i use oracle driver or mysql driver.

The output that i would is:

> 2015-10-23 with mysql driver
>
> 23-OCT-15  with oracle driver

Thank you

Comment: `alter session set nls_date_format=` .. you have problems with implicit datatype conversion.

Comment: I don't want to operate on db session because  the project has to run on different db without change it. I would move project from db to another changing only jdbc driver and connection parameters.

Comment: Why not refactor the places that give you problems to use `PreparedStatement` instead? There's no clean way to do what you're asking, so your choices are a) create a really ugly hack and b) do some refactoring to be able to use `ps.setDate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use dateformat to get consistent date string.

The following code formats a date and time according to the pattern String passed to the SimpleDateFormat constructor. The String returned by the format method contains the formatted date and time that are to be displayed.

```
Date today;
String output;
SimpleDateFormat formatter;
String pattern="yyyy-MM-dd";
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, currentLocale);
today = new Date();
output = formatter.format(today);
System.out.println(pattern + " " + output);
```